# How to remove a URL segment when debugging in Visual Studio via IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2012

According to a document "[How to: Specify a Port for the ASP.NET Development Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.ASPX)". For example, if you are testing a page called MyPage.aspx, when you run the page on the Visual Studio Development Server, the URL of the page might be the following:

`http://localhost:31544/MyPage.aspx`

Since IIS Express is the default web server for web application projects in Visual Studio 2012. I changed my project's Properties as described below:

[image]

Previously, I was able to debug my .Net MVC project with that approach without any problem.

But recently, the second URL's segment is being generated randomly every time I debug my project something like below:

`http://localhost:5086/(S(ffi1hjahbgr1qcwzhziq2wo3))/MyPage.aspx`

`http://localhost:5086/(S(m3nq32tgyznmc04s5htp1exo))/MyPage.aspx`

What should I do to remove the second segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have configured [ASP.NET Cookieless sessions for your ASP.NET application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479315.aspx). This will generate the type of Url you're seeing.

ASP.NET MVC doesn't support this feature, so you'll need to turn it off.

In your web.config look up the `<authentication><forms>` element and [set the `cookieless` option to `useCookie`](https://books.google.nl/books?id=RCVoZfzs6hwC&pg=PA166&lpg=PA166&dq=cookieless%3D%22usecookie%22&source=bl&ots=dYiURmb_gc&sig=vFj4KPOVqg1iCipObHQT1lzyXrw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5zNKpk_jOAhXCvRoKHeBXC3MQ6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=cookieless%3D%22usecookie%22&f=false). ASP.NET MVC doesn't support the other values and there are known security vulnerabilites concerning the Cookieless session feature, since te URI token can easily be intercepted using Javascript and man-in-the-middle setups, allowing others to easily hijaak the session.

See also:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/a/17733
- https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/cookieless-authentication-enabled

Comment: You are right, a few weeks ago I added a `sessionState` tag with a `cookieless` attribute in my local development but not in production environment. By changing `<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="60" />` to `<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="60" />` solves the issue. Thanks a million.